# How to connect mongodb on linux-host and mongo-express in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

I have installed mongodb successfully on a linux-host (redhat 8). mongosh is working perfectly and mongod listens on port 27017. I'd like to install mongo-express as docker container and connect it to mongod running on the host-machine (outside docker!). I have tried the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: always
       # ports:
       #     - 8081:8081
        environment:
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: localhost
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${MONGO_USER}
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASS}
            ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: ${MONGO_USER}
            ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASS}
        network_mode: host
```

**I commented out the port-settings as incompatible with network_mode:host.**

**Result:** The container will be built and gives this warnings:

```
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  | Welcome to mongo-express
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  | ------------------------
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: not authorized on config to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: {}, cursor: {}, nameOnly: false, lsid: { id: UUID("2e2c2b92-4d5d-47d0-9c37-59e52dd3a5df") }, $db: "config" }
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at Connection.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:453:61)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at processMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  |     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Trying to access mongo-express on host gives:

```
[root@d20p280a mongoexpress]# curl localhost:8081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Connection refused
```

**docker ps:**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                PORTS                                              NAMES
5cc00d871e82   mongo-express       "tini -- /docker-ent…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes                                                            mongoexpress-mongo-express-1
```

Any hint appreciated - thanks!

Comment: mongo-express --url mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: are you able to run this?

Comment: can you try **    -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL="mongodb://mongo:27017" 
**

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA: Running on the host-machine? Gives "Command not found". Where should this mongo-express-command come from?

Comment: ```can you try ** -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL="mongodb://mongo:27017" ** ``` gives me ```Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://mongo:27017"``` . It seems that mongo-express has no problem to connect to the mongod (via host-network), but the mongo-express server is unreachable from host.

Comment: in your file below are commented uncomment it and run again. 
 # ports:
       #     - 8081:8081

Comment: Port-Setting is ignored when using network_mode host. Thank you nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

The devil lies in the details, as always. The missing clue was this entry in the error log:

```
mongoexpress-mongo-express-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: not authorized on config to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: {}, cursor: {}, nameOnly: false, lsid: { id: UUID("2e2c2b92-4d5d-47d0-9c37-59e52dd3a5df") }, $db: "config" }
```

The docker-compose.yml is correct as shown. The admin user in mongodb has only the following roles: `"userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"` which are missing the *listCollections* privilege.
Strange though, that mongo-express didn't even start the server. I would have expected an error message in the webbrowser.
Thanks to all who took time to examine the problem.
This is the admin role in use now:

```
roles: [
    {
        role: 'root',
        db: 'admin'
    }
]
```